# Python runs code even though it is in an elif statement

Tags: list, python-3.x

I have a list and an input. I am running code like this:

```
findgtin=input("Enter code to find:")
ProductGtin=[]
ProductGtin.append(56231878)
#list is appended three more times but i cut this bit out#

##IF GTIN CODE EXISTS IN LIST##    
    for word in ProductGtin:
               ##IF GTIN CODE EXISTS:##
                if word==findgtin:
               ##MAIN CODE HERE##
        ##IF GTIN CODE DOES NOT EXIST:##
                if word!=findgtin:
                print ("PRODUCT NOT FOUND")
```

findgtin is an input from the user and ProductGtin is a list that contains several 8-digit numbers.
Whenever I run the program, I enter the first input and it prints "PRODUCT NOT FOUND" three times. There are four items in the list. The input, 56231878 is the first in the ProductGtin list.

I kind of know what is happening here, the program finds the input in the list and runs the main program and then checks the same input against the other items in the list as well, returning PRODUCT NOT FOUND. I have tried re-ordering the if and elif statements and this did not work. 
I would appreciate any help, thank you! :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

yes, is as you said.

try with this

```
ProductGtin = [56231878, ... ] 
# no need to do 4 individual appends, make the list with all 4 numbers at once

findgtin = int(input("Enter code to find:")) 
#transform the input to int, or store the ProductGtin as strings

if findgtin in ProductGtin:
    # the in operator will tell you if that element is in the list
    ##MAIN CODE HERE##
else:
    print ("PRODUCT NOT FOUND")
```